# II want to change a value comes from api in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I want to change a value coming from API and its Boolean in React Native but even when I click on it the value is still false, but I want it to become notifications.read true on Press

Here is my code

```
                             `<TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    {notifications.read == true}
                                    console.log(notifications.read)
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text style={{
                                    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.primaryColor,
                                    lineHeight: 18,
                                   letterSpacing: 0.1,
                                }}>
                                   </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>`
```

Answer (score 0):

we use **==** when we want to check the value of the variable equal to something. instead use **=**

```
`<TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    notifications.read = true
                                    console.log(notifications.read)
                                }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sample = () => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState({read:false});
  
  const handle_notif_status = () => {
    let new_status = {read:true};
    setNotifications(new_status);
  }

}
```

**strong text**

now on your onPress method call handle_notif_status

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` in `{notifications.read == true}` is redundant and also the `==` makes this statement a comparison. Change this line to `notifications.read = true` to fix.